# Allow scroll past bottom of shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I insert new elements into my Shiny app, I want the last element to be at the top and thus have the ability to scroll past the bottom of the shinydashboard.

For example, in the following Shiny app, after enough of the `h3("test")` elements are inserted such that a scrollbar is necessary, how do I enable scrolling past the bottom of the app so that the final "test" is at the top of the screen?

Bonus points if the last inserted element is automatically positioned at the top of the screen (automatic scrolling).

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      div(id="test",
          actionButton("bttn", "bttn"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  observeEvent(input$bttn, {
    insertUI("#test", "afterEnd", ui = tagList(h3("test"), h3("test"), h3("test")))
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

One approach is to create an empty element after the first `div` element. You can give this new element a relative height measure so it always fills up the remaining space on the bottom:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(fluidPage(
                      div(id = "test",
                          actionButton("bttn", "bttn")),
                      div(style = "width: 100%; height: 90vh")
                    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$bttn, {
    insertUI("#test", "afterEnd", ui = tagList(h3("test"), h3("test"), h3("test")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've used `90vh` so the element's height is `90%` of the viewport's height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units